# Custom JSON Deserialization in Jackson, exclude invalide array

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I receive data in JSON

```
{
"status": "INVALID_DATA",
"errors":{ "invalid_id": "Id isn't available",
           ...
           "wrong_address": "Address error msg"
         }
}
```

Keys and their quantity in structure "errors" are unknown for me. I'm trying to map this with class

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class StatusErrors
{
    private String status;
    private HashMap<String, String> errors = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getErrors() {
        return errors;
    }

    public void setErrors(HashMap<String, String> errors) {
        this.errors = errors;
    }
}
```

It works fine if I have "errors", but when server say "OK" and has no errors it send me

```
{
"status": "OK",
"errors":[]
}
```

(Don't ask me who write the server)
So mapper crashes.
I'm trying to write a custom JsonDeserializer (generic way)

```
public abstract class ExcludeEmptyArrayDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<T> {

    private final Class<T> clazz;

    protected ExcludeEmptyArrayDeserializer(Class<T> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec oc = jp.getCodec();
        JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jp);

        if(node.has("errors")) {
            if (node.get("errors").isArray() && !node.get("errors").getElements().hasNext())
                ((ObjectNode)node).remove("errors");
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return objectMapper.readValue(node, clazz);   // doesn't work
        //return oc.treeToValue(node, clazz);   // doesn't work too
    }
}

public class StatusErrorsDeserializer extends ExcludeEmptyArrayDeserializer<StatusErrors> {
    public StatusErrorsDeserializer() {
        super(StatusErrors.class);
    }
}
```

The result usage code has a view

```
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("", Version.unknownVersion());
    module.addDeserializer(StatusErrors.class, new StatusErrorsDeserializer());

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY).withModule(module); 
    MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter messageConverter = new MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter();
    messageConverter.setObjectMapper(mapper);

    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().clear();
    getRestTemplate().getMessageConverters().add(messageConverter);
```

The "errors" node deleted correctly but this solution still doesn't work.
I suppose I make a mistake in JsonDeserializer.deserialize method but don't get an idea.

BTW StatusErrors class can be a base class for other complicated messages from server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution is to change errors variable declaration to Object:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
class StatusErrors {
    private String status;
    private Object errors;
    public Map<String, String> getErrorsMap() {
        if (this.errors instanceof Map) {
            return (Map)this.errors;
        }
        return null;
    }
....
```

You don't need any serializers and deserializers:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

StatusErrors result1 = objectMapper.readValue(JSON1, StatusErrors.class);
System.out.println(result1);
System.out.println(result1.getErrors().getClass());
System.out.println(result1.getErrorsMap());
StatusErrors result2 = objectMapper.readValue(JSON2, StatusErrors.class);
System.out.println(result2);
```

The code above will print:

```
StatusErrors(status=INVALID_DATA, errors={invalid_id=Id isn't available, wrong_address=Address error msg})
class java.util.LinkedHashMap
{invalid_id=Id isn't available, wrong_address=Address error msg}
StatusErrors(status=OK, errors=[])
```